# How to download data more than limit of option "limit" and "skip"

Tags: api, openfda

I am using this api https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json. But as per limitation, we can't pass limit more than 100 and value for Skip is 25000.

But in the data, if we have more than 100K + record. How we can download entire data.

We are trying to creating a  code to fetch all NDC code while using this API. 
API used: "https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=finished:true&limit=100&skip=25000".
As a result, it provides Meta information:
{
  "meta": {
    "disclaimer": "Do not rely on openFDA to make decisions regarding medical care. While we make every effort to ensure that data is accurate, you should assume all results are unvalidated. We may limit or otherwise restrict your access to the API in line with our Terms of Service.",
    "terms": "https://open.fda.gov/terms/",
    "license": "https://open.fda.gov/license/",
    "last_updated": "2019-12-20",
    "results": {
      "skip": 0,
      "limit": 100,
      "total": 105845
    }

```
here total records count is **105845**, however when I try to fetch the record by skipping first 25000, its works fine, but it throws an error when Skip value is greater than **25000** :

{
```

"error": {
    "code": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "message": "Skip value must 25000 or less."
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

I'm Jack with the openFDA team. You can download entire datasets including NDC from [this page](https://open.fda.gov/downloads/). My apologies for the very delayed response; thank you for your patience.

Answer (score -1):

I would send them an email.

Depending on what you need it for and where you are based, they might be quite interested to cooperate and provide you with other means of accessing larger amounts of data.

Comment: We are trying to creating a  code to fetch all NDC code while using this API. API used: "https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=finished:true&limit=100".